# How to gather arrays of different sizes in the same array with Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Context:** I have 3 arrays. `A` that is *3x3*, `B` that is *5x2*, and `C` that is a *3D* array.

**Question:** Is there a way to stack arrays of different sizes along the 1st dimension of a 3D array, with Numpy ?

**Example:** if `A` and `B` are stacked in `C` along its first dimension, and I want to access `A`, I would type `C[0]`.

**Problem:** I know I can use Xarray for that, but I wanted to know if there was a Numpy way to do it. So far, I have been artificially extending the arrays with NaNs to match their sizes (see code below).

**Code:**

```
# Generate the arrays
A = np.random.rand(3,3)
B = np.random.rand(5,2)
C = np.zeros((2,5,3))

# Resize the arrays to fit C
AR = np.full([C.shape[1], C.shape[2]], np.nan) # Generate an array full of NaNs that fits C
AR[:A.shape[0],:A.shape[1]] = A # Input the previous array in the resized one
BR = np.full([C.shape[1], C.shape[2]], np.nan) # Generate an array full of NaNs that fits C
BR[:B.shape[0],:B.shape[1]] = B # Input the previous array in the resized one

# Stack the resized arrays in C
C[0] = AR
C[1] = BR
```

Comment: Give a concrete example. Actual data for your three inputs and the Exact structure you expect as output.

Comment: It is now updated

Comment: Why do you want a 3D array rather than simply a list of arrays `C=[A,B]`? What benefit will you gain here?

Comment: Well I didn't know I could simply use a list, I assumed C had to be a numpy array in order to host other arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to slice it as freely, but you can use `dtype = 'object'` when making a jagged array.

```
jagged_array = np.array([np.zeros((3, 2)), np.zeros((5, 2)), np.zeros((3, 2, 5))], dtype = 'object')
```